# What kind of object detection model is required?

Tags: object-detection, graphs, object-recognition

I have some images, and my task is to build an object detection model for detecting tables and equipment photos in the image. The target would be detecting objects (table and equipment), so I can crop the detected parts into separate images. But I also need a relational map between the table and equipment part to understand which equipment image belongs to which table after cropping out the image. I have given a sample of the image, but not all image samples are not as simple as this one.
[image]

Now, what would be the approach to solving this problem? I have some sort of object detection knowledge, but how will I deal with object relationships? Any thoughts or suggestions?